# Generete random ID SQlite3 using Tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, treeview, auto-increment

I am trying to build a Library GUI using the TKinter Library. I have a TreeView showing the data from the database but I want the ID column to be automatically generated. The Code for creating the table is commented because I already ran it once and I did create the table.
[The error I am getting is this.<<<<<<<<](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkJ6Z.png)

```
def Add_New():
    #Create Second Window
    add_win=Toplevel()
    add_win.geometry("500x310")
    add_win.title("Add a new item")
    #Create a database or connect to one
    conn=sqlite3.connect('warehouse.db')
    #Create cursor
    c=conn.cursor()
    #Create Table ONLY ONCE after that comment it.
    #c.execute("""CREATE TABLE inventory(
    #   id_no integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
    #   customer_name text,
    #   part_no integer,
    #   tool_no text,
    #   descr_item_produced text,
    #   customer_prod_code text,
    #   location_item text,
    #   bar_code text,
    #   notes_comments text
    #   )""")
    #Commit Changes
    conn.commit()
    #Create Submit Function for New Item
    def submit():
        conn=sqlite3.connect('warehouse.db')
        #Create cursor
        c=conn.cursor() 
        #Insert Into Table
        c.execute("INSERT INTO inventory VALUES(:c_name,:p_no,:t_no,:d_item,:c_code,:l_item,:b_code,:n_comm)",
                {   
                    
                    'c_name' : c_name.get(),
                    'p_no' : p_no.get(),
                    't_no':t_no.get(),
                    'd_item':d_item.get(),
                    'c_code':c_code.get(),
                    'l_item':l_item.get(),
                    'b_code':b_code.get(),
                    'n_comm':n_comm.get(),
                })
        #Commit Changes
        conn.commit()
        #Close Connection with db
        conn.close()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `NULL` as the content of the autoincrement field `id_no` in the INSERT statement:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO inventory VALUES(NULL,:c_name,:p_no,:t_no,:d_item,:c_code,:l_item,:b_code,:n_comm)",
    {   
        'c_name' : c_name.get(),
        'p_no' : p_no.get(),
        't_no':t_no.get(),
        'd_item':d_item.get(),
        'c_code':c_code.get(),
        'l_item':l_item.get(),
        'b_code':b_code.get(),
        'n_comm':n_comm.get(),
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you gave `AUTOINCREMENT` for the `id_no` ,I'd rather do it as in the following method and remove the `AUTOINCREMENT` from the constrains:

```
def id_no():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                   user='root',
                                   passwd='root',
                                   database='warehouse')
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "select id_no from warehouse"
    mycursor.execute(sql)
    rows = mycursor.fetchall()
    for i in rows :
        id_no = i
    try:
        return id_no[0]+1
    except:
        return int(1)
    mydb.close()
```

and pass the function `id_no()` in the `submit()` function.
You should include the `id_no` column in executing sql command to avoid the error.

Also to automatically set the correct number after deleting a row from the table,
use the following sql commands.

```
sql1 = "SET @rank:=0;"
sql2 = "update patients set id_no=@rank :=@rank+1;"

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                               user='root',
                               passwd='root',
                               database='warehouse')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute(sql1)
mycursor.execute(sql2)
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

Hope that answers your question.